# How to reformat all the open files in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, intellij-14, reformatting

Is there any shortcut to reformat the code in all the open files in IntelliJ? I'm specifically looking for a way to reformat all the **open files** inside editor and not all the files in project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest that I could recommend is to select the root folder from the project explorer and press alt+command+L(MAC OS).  Reformat Code window pops up. In the pop-up, select the scope as Open files and Click run.  It formats all the open files
[image]

Intellij Documentation -->https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-and-rearrange-code.html#reformat_module_directory